# Maven - Cannot resolve net.dv8tion:JDA:4.3.0_234

Tags: java, maven, discord

I try to code a discord bot, but i have an issue while making the project.

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0_234</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>dv8tion</id>
        <name>m2-dv8tion</name>
        <url>https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

net.dv8tion, JDA and the VERSION number are in red, i have no clue how to fix this. I tried to reload Maven, reload intellij but nothing helps.

Comment: Do you do a maven update? It seems to works fine. Check also if you can reach https://m2.dv8tion.net, maybe a proxy is blocking you.

Comment: This version does not exist. See https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases/net/dv8tion/JDA/maven-metadata.xml for available versions. You might have confused 234 and 324.

Comment: Thanks, the issue seemed to be the version...